# Kitchen drawer replacement handle

Tags: kitchens, replacement

I’m looking to change the drawer handles on my kitchen drawers. I’m totally flummoxed how to remove the handles as there are three different screws and can’t figure out what does what. I assume some are for adjustment but which will allow me to access the screws to remove the handles. Any help appreciated

Comment: How about a few pictures.

Comment: Handles usually not adjustable, just on or off, but three screws are unusual.  Are you talking about handles you pull to open the drawer or the hinges/tracks?

Answer (score 2):

Pictures would help immensely. Please edit some in. Without them, guessing:

Given this is for **drawers** if the handle attachment is not obvious (screw behind the point where the handle connects) I'll have to suspect false-fronts on drawer boxes, so the handle would be attached to the false front and the false front attached to the drawer box.

If there's a screw behind the handle attachment point and some other screws, leave the other screws alone. If there's no screw behind the handle attachment, you probably have to remove the whole false front from the drawer box to access the handle attachment.